# Choose $k$ distinct integers uniformly from $\{x_1,\cdots,x_n\}$. Find expectation of their sum.

Tags: probability

> Let $\{x_1,\cdots,x_n\}$ be $n$ given distinct integers. Randomly choose $k$ ($k < n$) distinct integers from them, and let them be $y_1,\cdots,y_k$. Find $E(y_1 + \cdots + y_k)$.

I considered the case where $k=2$, and I got something like

\begin{align}
E(y_1 + y_2) &= E(y_1) + E(y_2)\\
&= \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nx_i + \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n\left(\frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{j\ne i} x_j\right)\\
&= \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n x_i + \frac{1}{n}\frac{1}{n-1} (n-1)\sum_{i=1}^n x_i\\
&= \frac{2}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n x_i
\end{align}

, and haven't consulted external source to check whether it's correct or not.

I am wondering if we generalize $k$ to be greater than $2$, is there any "good-looking" expression for the expectation, even though my feeling tells me that the answer is "no"?

Comment: I'd have expected the expected value to be k times the average. is that not the case?

Comment: Continuing from before, simple case of 1, 2, 3 and k = 2. 3 possible pairs, (1,2), (2,3), (1,3). average sum here is (3 + 5 + 4) / 3 = 4, which is 2 * 2, as i'd have expected

Comment: @muzzlator Actually you just reminded me that I could simplify the expression I found

Comment: Use linearity of expectation and realize that the rvs have identical distribution

Comment: sigh, found another mistake, editing shortly :) it's 6am so i have an excuse

Comment: @muzzlator  The beauty of Linearity of Expectation is that it does not require independence.

Comment: Hm, good call, maybe my intuition was better than my LaTeX algebra skills

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: Made silly mistakes in my first few attempts, looks like I may have been wrong in my comment:

Edit 2: My first comment was actually right I think, and hopefully the direct computation below is right as well.

Fix $y_i$ and note that it appears in ${n-1} \choose {k-1}$ terms in all possible sums it is in. We have a total of $n \choose k$ total combinations of $k$ elements and so the total contribution to the average for $y_i$ is: $$\frac{{n-1 \choose {k-1}}}{n \choose k} y_i = \frac{\frac{(n-1)!}{(k-1)!(n-k)!}}{\frac{n!}{(n-k)!k!}} y_i= \frac{(n-1)!(n-k)!k!}{(k-1)!(n-k)!n!} y_i = \frac{k}{n} y_i$$.

Comment: sorry, I had a gazillion errors in trying to type up an answer quickly, redid it a little more slowly and I think I get what i originally expected

Answer (score 0):

Let's sum up all the possible $(y_1+...+y_k)=E$ and group up all the $x_i$. Let's say there are $N$ such equations.

On the left side we will have $(a_1*x_1+...+a_n*x_n)$

Because of the symmetry all the $a_i$ are the same here: $a_i=a$. And we have $k*a=n*N$ (this is a total number of x's on the left side).

Expected value would be $a*(x_1+...+x_n)/N = (x_1+...+x_n)*k/n$